Why 'constructor' attributed function with the same name is called 3 times from library X instead of 1 time from libraries X, Y, Z
Scenario:
$ cat lib.c
#include <stdio.h>
#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)
#define CAT_(x,y) x##y
#define CAT(x,y) CAT_(x,y)

__attribute__((constructor))
void CAT(foo,)(void) { printf("foo" STR(N) " %p\n", CAT(foo,)); }
void CAT(bar,N)(void){ puts("bar" STR(N)); }

$ cat main.c
void barx(void);
void bary(void);
void barz(void);

int main(void)
{
    barx();
    bary();
    barz();
}

$ cat build_run.sh
gcc lib.c -DN=x -c -fPIC -o libx.o && gcc libx.o -o libx.so -shared &&
gcc lib.c -DN=y -c -fPIC -o liby.o && gcc liby.o -o liby.so -shared &&
gcc lib.c -DN=z -c -fPIC -o libz.o && gcc libz.o -o libz.so -shared &&
gcc -L. -o main main.c -lx -ly -lz &&
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./main

$ bash build_run.sh
foox 0x7f0bf002e139
foox 0x7f0bf002e139
foox 0x7f0bf002e139
barx
bary
barz

Here we see that:

All .so libraries have constructor attributed function with the same name foo.
Function foo is called 3 times from library X (which may be unexpected behavior) instead of 1 time from libraries X, Y, Z (which may be expected behavior).

As I understand, addresses of constructor attributed functions foo are placed (directly or indirectly) in .init_array section. Hence, function names are expected to be irrelevant.
The core question: why function foo is called 3 times from library X instead of 1 time from libraries X, Y, Z?

Extra observations:

If we change in lib.c from CAT(foo,) to CAT(foo,N) and rerun the build_run.sh, then we will see:

$ bash build_run.sh
fooz 0x7fc121dcc139
fooy 0x7fc121dd1139
foox 0x7fc121dd6139
barx
bary
barz

which may be expected behavior.

Running the original (i.e. with CAT(foo,)) example on Cygwin leads to function foo is called 1 time from libraries X, Y, Z (which may be expected behavior).


System and software info:
$ uname -a
Linux xxx 5.15.0-79-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 10 16:07:21 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0


UPD. 1) I've tried to add -Bsymbolic to gcc libx.o -o libx.so -shared (to each library), which is "When creating a shared library, bind references to global symbols to the definition within the shared library, if any." However, I didn't help. 2) By some reason I cannot make constructor attributed functions static.

I think it is an example of symbol interposition.
When loading shared libraries, the dynamic linker (Linux) resolves symbols (function names, variables) globally by default. If two or more shared libraries define the same symbol (e.g., foo), the first-loaded version of the symbol is used for all subsequent references.
Potential fixes:

I believe, you can use the -Bsymbolic linker option when compiling each shared library but I never tested it myself.
Making them static should also be effective

Cygwin uses DLL libraries instead and Windows has a different mechanism.In Windows, each DLL has a distinct address space for its functions and variables, meaning symbol names are resolved independently within each DLL rather than globally across all loaded libraries.

Re: "dynamic linker (Linux) resolves symbols (function names, variables) globally by default" and "In Windows, ... symbol names are resolved independently within each DLL": are they assumptions or known facts? If known facts, then it would be useful to provide references (if any). (My explanation of the difference in behavior is nearly the same, however, I have no specialized knowledge on the subject.)

Indeed: -Bsymbolic is "When creating a shared library, bind references to global symbols to the definition within the shared library, if any." I've added -Bsymbolic to gcc libx.o -o libx.so -shared (to each library) and rerun the build_run.sh: function foo is still called 3 times from library X instead of 1 time from libraries X, Y, Z.

Extra questions: 1) About dynamic linker (Linux): what is the rationale for resolving symbols (function names, variables) globally by default (instead of independently within each shared object / library)? 2) Why doesn't GCC produce any diagnostics (even with -pedantic -Wall -Wextra) if two or more shared libraries define the same symbol?

are they assumptions or known facts? known to me - answering the questions is sharing my own knowledge. I do not have to search for sources. Rationale: I think the best person to ask is Linus

FYI: I've changed -Bsymbolic to -Wl,-Bsymbolic and it works.

@pmor that exactly what i meant "you can use the -Bsymbolic linker option" -Wl is to pass option to the linker


Hence, function names are expected to be irrelevant.

No. They are still relevant. When dynamic library is loaded, OS is assigning each function an actual address. If two libraries has the same name, the function from the first loaded library is used, and function from second loaded library is ignored.
This leads to a behavior you observed. The first library loads, registers foo(), runs it. The second library on load sees that foo() is already registered, in the space of this process, and runs it.
Since you intent for the foo to be a constructor - then simply adding static to the foo definition will solve the issue. In this case, the function will not be visible outside the dynamic library and would, therefore be exempt from the name duplication between two libraries.
Of course, you will loose ability to call foo() from outside the lib.c. If it still be needed - then you must have different names for the constructor functions (which you do by using CAT(foo,N)).

"OS is assigning each function an actual address. If two libraries has the same name, the function from the first loaded library is used," - no, it depends on dynamic linking implementation. Windows & Linux behave differently

I refer to the accepted answer at Multiple shared library constructors not being called
for a short explanation of why the problem behaviour is expected and the usual way of avoiding it. I'll just address your reported difficulties
in pre-empting the unwanted behaviour in practice (which are confined to the linux build, since the Cygwin Windows build follows Windows DLL dynamic linkage protocol and fulfils your expectations).
There are 4 ways you can do it. I'll demonstrate them with the following files.
$ tail -n +1 *.c Makefile
==> lib.c <==
#include <stdio.h>
#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)
#define CAT_(x,y) x##y
#define CAT(x,y) CAT_(x,y)

#ifndef LINKAGE
#define LINKAGE
#endif

LINKAGE void CAT(foo,)(void) { printf("foo" STR(N) " %p\n", CAT(foo,)); }
void CAT(bar,N)(void){ puts("bar" STR(N)); }

==> main.c <==
void barx(void);
void bary(void);
void barz(void);

int main(void)
{
    barx();
    bary();
    barz();
}

==> Makefile <==
.PHONY: all clean run

all run: ./main

run:
    ./main

LIBS := libx.so liby.so libz.so

./main: main.o $(LIBS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< -L. -lx -ly -lz -Wl,-rpath=.
    
$(LIBS:.so=.o): lib.c
    $(CC) -DN=$(patsubst lib%.o,%,$@) -DLINKAGE='$(LINKAGE)' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o $@ $<

%.so: %.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o $@ $< 

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so ./main

    

The compile recipe in Makefile contains the unnecessary option -save-temps just to save the intermediate files
so that I can show you the generated definition of foo.
The linkage recipe contains -rpath=. just so that ./main can load ./lib[x|y|z].so without help.
$(LDFLAGS) is empty unless I define it when I run make.
First let's check the default behaviour:
$ make run
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc -DN=x -DLINKAGE='' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libx.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libx.so libx.o 
cc -DN=y -DLINKAGE='' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o liby.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o liby.so liby.o 
cc -DN=z -DLINKAGE='' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libz.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libz.so libz.o 
cc -o main main.o -L. -lx -ly -lz -Wl,-rpath=.
./main
barx
bary
barz

The generated definition of foo is:
$ grep 'foo(void)' libx.i 
       void foo(void) { printf("foo" "x" " %p\n", foo); }

And:
$ readelf --syms --wide libx.so | egrep \(Symbol\|Num\|foo\)
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     8: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 foo
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 28 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    25: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 foo
    

In lib[x|y|z].so, foo is an external (GLOBAL) function defined in section #14 ( = .text),
with default visibility in both the global and dynamic symbol tables.
Then the unwanted behaviour, for constructor-attributed foo:
$ make clean
rm -f *.o *.so ./main
$ make LINKAGE=[[gnu::constructor]] run
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc -DN=x -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libx.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libx.so libx.o 
cc -DN=y -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o liby.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o liby.so liby.o 
cc -DN=z -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libz.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libz.so libz.o 
cc -o main main.o -L. -lx -ly -lz -Wl,-rpath=.
./main
foox 0x7bba97b97139
foox 0x7bba97b97139
foox 0x7bba97b97139
barx
bary
barz

The generated definition of foo is:
$ grep 'foo(void)' libx.i 
[[gnu::constructor]] void foo(void) { printf("foo" "x" " %p\n", foo); }

[[gnu:...]] is a newer more compact syntax for the legacy __attribute__((...)). And:
$ readelf --syms --wide libx.so | egrep \(Symbol\|Num\|foo\)
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     8: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 foo
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 28 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    25: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 foo
    

No change to the linkage of foo.
Then on to the evasive measures.
You can declare `constructor`-attributed `foo` as ` static`
$ make clean
rm -f *.o *.so ./main
$ make LINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]] static' run
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc -DN=x -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]] static' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libx.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libx.so libx.o 
cc -DN=y -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]] static' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o liby.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o liby.so liby.o 
cc -DN=z -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]] static' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libz.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libz.so libz.o 
cc -o main main.o -L. -lx -ly -lz -Wl,-rpath=.
./main
fooz 0x726a21eea139
fooy 0x726a21eef139
foox 0x726a21ef4139
barx
bary
barz

The behaviour is as desired. The generated definition of foo is:
$ grep 'foo(void)' libx.i 
[[gnu::constructor]] static void foo(void) { printf("foo" "x" " %p\n", foo); }

And:
$ readelf --syms --wide libx.so | egrep \(Symbol\|Num\|foo\)
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 28 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    10: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 foo

Now foo is altogether invisible (LOCAL) to the linkers. It is bound to the internal definition
in the lib[x|y|z].o object file, at compiletime, for each shared library.
I don't know of a good reason why you wouldn't be content to make a constructor
function static, so you can probably stop here. In case you have some reason for foo to remain declared external,
or are just curious as to how it could be done, there are three ways you can do that.
The `constructor`-attributed `foo` can also be attributed hidden dynamic linkage
$ make clean
rm -f *.o *.so ./main
$ make LINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("hidden")]]' run
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc -DN=x -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("hidden")]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libx.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libx.so libx.o 
cc -DN=y -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("hidden")]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o liby.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o liby.so liby.o 
cc -DN=z -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("hidden")]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libz.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libz.so libz.o 
cc -o main main.o -L. -lx -ly -lz -Wl,-rpath=.
./main
fooz 0x7b7fdaacb139
fooy 0x7b7fdaad0139
foox 0x7b7fdaad5139
barx
bary
barz

The generated definition of foo is:
$ grep 'foo(void)' libx.i 
[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("hidden")]] void foo(void) { printf("foo" "x" " %p\n", foo); }

And:
$ readelf --syms --wide libx.o | egrep \(Symbol\|Num\|foo\)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     4: 0000000000000000    41 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 foo
     

In the object file libx.o, foo becomes GLOBAL HIDDEN, visible to the static linker,
but only so that:
$ readelf --syms --wide libx.so | egrep \(Symbol\|Num\|foo\)
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 28 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    15: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   14 foo
    

it will be converted to LOCAL in the output image libx.so, thus invisible
for any further linkage.
The `constructor`-attributed `foo` can also be attributed protected dynamic linkage
$ make clean
rm -f *.o *.so ./main
$ make LINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("protected")]]' run
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc -DN=x -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("protected")]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libx.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libx.so libx.o 
cc -DN=y -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("protected")]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o liby.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o liby.so liby.o 
cc -DN=z -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("protected")]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libz.o lib.c
cc  -shared -o libz.so libz.o 
cc -o main main.o -L. -lx -ly -lz -Wl,-rpath=.
./main
fooz 0x7c9e5cfab139
fooy 0x7c9e5cfb0139
foox 0x7c9e5cfb5139
barx
bary
barz

The generated definition of foo is:
$ grep 'foo(void)' libx.i 
[[gnu::constructor,gnu::visibility("protected")]] void foo(void) { printf("foo" "x" " %p\n", foo); }

And in the object file libx.o:
$ readelf --syms --wide libx.o | egrep \(Symbol\|Num\|foo\)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     4: 0000000000000000    41 FUNC    GLOBAL PROTECTED    1 foo
     

which after linkage yields:
$ readelf --syms --wide libx.so | egrep \(Symbol\|Num\|foo\)
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     8: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    GLOBAL PROTECTED   14 foo
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 28 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    25: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    GLOBAL PROTECTED   14 foo
    

The static linker preserves the GLOBAL PROTECTED status of foo and exposes it
with the same status to the dynamic linker, but the effect of this status
is that the dynamic linker binds references to foo within a shared library
to the definition within that shared library.
That is a way of requiring, on a per-function basis, the same dynamic binding that
is required globally by the fourth and last method:
You can specify `-Bsymbolic` in the shared library linker options
$ make clean
rm -f *.o *.so ./main
$ make LINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]]' LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic run
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc -DN=x -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libx.o lib.c
cc -Wl,-Bsymbolic -shared -o libx.so libx.o 
cc -DN=y -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o liby.o lib.c
cc -Wl,-Bsymbolic -shared -o liby.so liby.o 
cc -DN=z -DLINKAGE='[[gnu::constructor]]' -save-temps -fPIC -c -o libz.o lib.c
cc -Wl,-Bsymbolic -shared -o libz.so libz.o 
cc -o main main.o -L. -lx -ly -lz -Wl,-rpath=.
./main
fooz 0x725e7e8a5139
fooy 0x725e7e8aa139
foox 0x725e7e8af139
barx
bary
barz

Here I set LDFLAGS for the first time. Note that to prompt gcc to pass a linker
option that is not a gcc option through to the linker, you must pass gcc the option
-Wl,<linker-option>.
The generated definition of foo reverts to:
$ grep 'foo(void)' libx.i 
[[gnu::constructor]] void foo(void) { printf("foo" "x" " %p\n", foo); }

And the linkage of foo reverts to:
$ readelf --syms --wide libx.so | egrep \(Symbol\|Num\|foo\)
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 9 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     8: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 foo
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 28 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    25: 0000000000001139    41 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 foo
    

But in this case all of the dynamically visible symbols in lib[x|y|z].so
will behave as if individually attributed visibility("protected")
